Python type and object implementations
Recently i accidentally saw a strange behaviour of Python:
The object class, which is inherited implicitly, doesn't have a __dict__. But every inherited class, even if you don't add anything to it (e.g. class A: pass), a __dict__ member is automaticly created. My only guess is that it's created by type() metaclass, but i can't find its realization. I have searched in the PyPy and CPython githubs and in Python's docs.
I found out that if you create class A: pass, dir(A) shows that even A has a __dict__ member. Well, now my question is, is it possible to see the type() realization anywhere?
